# Beautiful soup getting the first child

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I get the first child?

```
 <div class="cities"> 
       <div id="3232"> London </div>
       <div id="131"> York </div>
  </div>
```

How can I get London?

```
for div in nsoup.find_all(class_='cities'):
    print (div.children.contents)
```

AttributeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute 'contents'

Comment: `children` is a sequence of children, each one of which has `contents`. The sequence itself doesn't have `contents`. It's just like `[1, 2, 3]` isn't an integer. Meanwhile, like any sequence, to get the first value, you can just `next(iter(div.children))`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

div.children returns an iterator.

```
for div in nsoup.find_all(class_='cities'):
    for childdiv in div.find_all('div'):
        print (childdiv.string) #london, york
```

AttributeError was raised, because of non-tags like `'\n'` are in `.children`. just use proper child selector to find the specific div.

(more edit) can't reproduce your exceptions - here's what I've done:

```
In [137]: print foo.prettify()
<div class="cities">
 <div id="3232">
  London
 </div>
 <div id="131">
  York
 </div>
</div>

In [138]: for div in foo.find_all(class_ = 'cities'):
   .....:     for childdiv in div.find_all('div'):
   .....:         print childdiv.string
   .....: 
 London 
 York 

In [139]: for div in foo.find_all(class_ = 'cities'):
   .....:     for childdiv in div.find_all('div'):
   .....:         print childdiv.string, childdiv['id']
   .....: 
 London  3232
 York  131
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'contents'`, and when I use string instead of contents it gives `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: It prints None, None then RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: by `div['id']` or like `div.get('id', None)`. same as if you would retrieve something from a `dict`

Answer (score 15):

With modern versions of bs4 (certainly bs4 4.7.1+) you have access to :first-child css pseudo selector. Nice and descriptive. Use `soup.select_one` if you only want to return the first match i.e. `soup.select_one('.cities div:first-child').text`. It is considered good practice to test is `not None` before using `.text` accessor.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="cities"> 
       <div id="3232"> London </div>
       <div id="131"> York </div>
  </div>
  '''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml') #or 'html.parser'
first_children = [i.text for i in soup.select('.cities div:first-child')]
print(first_children)
```

Comment: How did you know the correct syntax for the css selector? I could not easily find how to make a css selector that selects the first child of a parent element with a certain class. My initial guess was that it would be `element.class:first-child` as `element.class` is used to select an element by class. And [w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) and [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) don't suggest how to do this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators @Übermensch

Answer (score 8):

The current accepted answer gets all cities, when the question only wanted the first.

If you only need the first child, you can take advantage of `.children` returning an iterator and not a list. Remember that an iterator generates list items on the fly, and because we only need the first element of the iterator, we don't ever need to generate all other city elements (thus saving time).

```
for div in nsoup.find_all(class_='cities'):
    first_child = next(div.children, None)
    if first_child is not None:
        print(first_child.string.strip())
```