# JSoup get first child of div

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a structure that looks like the following using `JSoup`.

```
<div class="bigClass">
    <a href="foo.com"> Field 1</a>
    <a href="bar.com"> Field 2</a>
    <a href="baz.com"> Field 3</a>
</div>
```

Right now, I'm using the following code to get **the entire textual contents of the div class "bigClass"**

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://foobar.com").userAgent(userAgent).timeout(1000).get();
price = doc.getElementsByClass("bigClass");
System.out.println(price.text());
```

How can I only get the first child ("Field 1"), regardless of the `<a>` class and URL?

Similar question for BeautifulSoup python: [Beautiful soup getting the first child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490718/beautiful-soup-getting-the-first-child)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you may be looking for

```
doc.getElementsByClass("bigClass").first().child(0)
```

- `getElementsByClass("bigClass")` returns all elements with `bigClass`
- but we want to get specific one (probably first)
- and on that first element select its first child (children nodes are indexed starting from 0).

Comment: Even easier / shorter: `doc.select("div.bigClass > a:first-child")`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use one of the two options below:

#### Option 1

```
doc.select("div.bigClass > a:first-of-type");
```

DEMO: [http://try.jsoup.org/~btbp8Fb1xrPf38dTYbplLz5lA3Y](http://try.jsoup.org/%7Ebtbp8Fb1xrPf38dTYbplLz5lA3Y)

#### Option 2

```
doc.select("div.bigClass > a:first-child");
```

DEMO: [http://try.jsoup.org/~mj8CAaWTtQEicyd75bSHDV3_KeA](http://try.jsoup.org/%7Emj8CAaWTtQEicyd75bSHDV3_KeA)