# Is there a way to return all first children of all elements in a Soup dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am writing a scraper that fetches Wine name, Wine Price, Wine ID and Wine availability from a website. Name, Price and ID is easy, but I struggle with the availability since the code of the website uses different div ID's depending on if it is available or not. If they used the same ID I could use that for all items found in the Soup. But now I see I need to first find Class with ID X, and then find the first child of that class. Inside that class is the text I am looking for.

```
wine_available_container = parsed_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"product-ordertostore"})
```

The class product-ordertostore either has a child named available, or not available. I need to iterate through the list and write to a file I have if the wine in question is available or not. If I search for the exact class "available" or "not_available" the soup only fetches these ones and not both. The page returns 25 wines at the time, and I need to get the availability of each one. Hope you understand what I try to do.

Comment: Some example urls and expected output?

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490718/beautiful-soup-getting-the-first-child)

Comment: If you inspect element on this URL you will find a DIV class named "product-ordertostore". Its first child is either SPAN class "icon-stock icon-in-store-not-available" or SPAN class "icon-stock icon-in-store-available".
I need to get both of them in my request to SOUP. And print out sequentially if a wine is available or not. As you can see on the site there are 24 wines on the page. Some are available, some are not. I fetch name, price and ID and print it to excel. I need the same with availability.

Comment: URL:    https://www.vinmonopolet.no/vmp/search?q=%3Arelevance%3AvisibleInSearch%3Atrue%3AmainCategory%3Ar%25C3%25B8dvin%3AmainCountry%3Afrankrike%3AmainDistrict%3Afrankrike_burgund%3Avolume%3A%255B75%2BTO%2B75%255D%3ApriceValue%3A%255B850%2BTO%2B6750%255D&page=7

Comment: Btw, thank you all for your help here., I am so stuck.